# Fairly distributing $k$ tickets among grouped applicants

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

## Problem description

Consider a set $G$, a function $s \colon G \to \mathbb N$ and a natural number $k \in \mathbb N$.

By abuse of notation, let $s(H) := \sum_{i\in H}s(i)$ for a subset $H \subseteq G$.

We are looking for for a probability distribution $P \colon \Omega \to [0,1]$ for $\Omega := \{H \subset G \mid s(H) = k\}$ that is *fair* in the sense that $P(i) := P(\{H \subseteq G \mid i \in H\})$ is the same for all $i\in G$. (In that case, $P(i) = \frac k {s(G)}$.)

For which $G$, $s$ and $k$ does such a $P$ exist? Can it be easily realized by some sequence of draws from an urn?

## Some thoughts

Clearly, there are inputs for which a *fair* $P$ exists, e.g. if $s(i) = 1$ for all $i\in G$.

More generally, $P$ exists if there is a partition $\mathcal G$ of $G$ such that for every $H\in \mathcal G$, $s(H) = h$ for some divisor $h$ of $k$.

There are instances beyond that that allow a solution, e.g. $s=(3,1,1,1,1)$ and $k=4$.

But there are also instances without solution. Clearly if $s(G) < k$, but also instances such as $s=(3,3,1)$ and $k=4$.

## Application

This problem arises if you have a lottery for, say, $k$ event tickets, you allow people to sign up in groups and want to guarantee that any group is either chosen completely, or not at all, while still giving each individual the same chance to a ticket.